# New Url Problum In No input file specified Solution Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I AM Using This .htaccess code for Solving
No input file specified Problum.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But After Add  "?" question mark in this line
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]   in this  line

my url changing  like        http://www.vaibhavjain.in/?/Weaver
in my last server my url was  http://www.vaibhavjain.in/Weaver

how Can I remove ? from my url

because  in google webmaster all my url listing without "?" question mark.

Comment: are you sure, that you insert your ```.htaccess``` file in Weaver folder?

Comment: Weaver Is a Php Page Not Folder.

Comment: ok. please replace that line with this code ```RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]```

Comment: Now Url Is 
http://www.vaibhavjain.in/?Weaver

remove only  /  not  ?

I am Looking Like this
http://www.vaibhavjain.in/Weaver

Answer (score 0):

This `.htaccess` code is working for me. Try this.

DirectoryIndex index.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Replace your current code with above provided code and check please.